# Django JavaScript translation not working

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext

I tried to [follow the guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code) but it's not clear enough.

1. I added this to my urls.py

   ```
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       (r'^jsi18n/(?P<packages>\S+?)/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),
   )
   ```
2. Generated the lang files using this command:

   ```
   django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l fr
   ```

`root_folder/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES` now contain `django.po` & `djangojs.po` and `alert(gettext('this is to be translated'));` in one of my js files was picked up in `djangojs.po`.

1. I ran `django-admin.py compilemessages` and restarted the server.
2. Added this to my base.html:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog' 'locale' %}" >< /script >
   ```

Note that I added 'locale' to avoid the exception of not passing the package name when dynamically loading translations.

1. Visited `/jsi18n/locale/` from my browser and all I get is Django translation functions:

   ```
   /* gettext library */

   var catalog = new Array();

   function pluralidx(count) { return (count == 1) ? 0 : 1; }


   function gettext(msgid) {
   ....
   ```

Why 'this is to be translated' is not showing and on which basis it will show a specific language without passing it with the URL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know exactly how to solve your problem, but I can tell you, how things work for me:

The `locale` folder is inside my `tickets` app.

urls.py

```
js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('tickets',),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
    ...
```

base.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
```

and to create message file:

```
python -m django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l fr
python -m django-admin compilemessages
```

Hopefully you can pick something up from this.

Answer (score 6):

For others with my particular case, js messages are generated and compiled OK but not rendered in templates or pages when you use i18n language urls.

This is because javascript catalog should be added to i18n urls patterns, not to normal patterns.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict), )
```

=>

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('', (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict), )
```

Comment: Thank you indeed, I spent many hours on this. I have opened a relevant [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25751) to correct the docs that -in my eyes- are not functional.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this: from what I understand reading the comments in the aforementioned ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25751, this seems to happen only when your _root_ url is using `i18n_patterns` (can someone confirm - or infirm - this ?)