# Django - Javascript internationalization: translation not rendered in site

Tags: javascript, python, django, internationalization

I have followed the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code).

`./manage.py makemessages -d djangojs` works fine.

`./manage.py compilemessages` created the relevant `.po` files

However, the translation is not performed on site.

urls.py

```
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('market',),
}

urlpatterns = [url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict), ]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
)
```

settings.py

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    pjoin(BASE_DIR, '00', 'locale'),
)

# Middleware ===================================================================
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

# Internationalization =========================================================
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext_noop('English')),
    ('fr', gettext_noop('French')),
)
```

home.html (The script is successfully loaded)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625102/django-javascript-translation-not-working/27147542#comment55164743_27147542), which states that

> javascript catalog should be added to i18n urls patterns, not to
>   normal patterns.

Therefore urls.py must be changed to:

```
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('market',),
}

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict),
)
```

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code) will be [updated](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25751) accordingly:

> We should add a note in the i18n_patterns documentation stating: if used all translated content views must also be placed within it.